# Initialization of class-to-table mapping in Azure's offline-sync API

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

Azure's offline-sync API does not offer a full ORM, but does provide basic class-to-table mapping.

The [sample project](http://github.com/lindydonna/xamarin-forms-offline-sync/tree/master/XamarinFormsOffline)'s `TodoItemManager` has this:

```
store.DefineTable<TodoItem>();
```

*Should this be done on the mobile app's first run only, or is it safe to call each time it starts?* Hence, does it perform a "create if not exists" sort of operation?

And, what if the class' schema changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Mobile Apps does the equivalent of a "create if not exists" on your SQLite database - it's safe to call it each time your app starts.

Comment: If my class changes, will the API automatically update the mapped table's schema? In other words, is there an official way for us to handle migrations?

Comment: @hbob If you add columns, the SDK will add them to the local store. However, it's not true migration support--the new columns will have null values, for instance and the SDK does not drop columns. For true migration support, you would have to implement your own local store layer. See https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/blob/master/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore/MobileServiceSQLiteStore.cs#L487.

Answer (score 1):

The Data Sync service syncs data only. While it’s capable of creating the corresponding tables being synched on a member database during provisioning, it only creates the bare minimum to be able to sync. It will not create or sync stored procedures, triggers or views from the source database. If you want the target database members to have a full fidelity copy of the database schema from the source, you can script the source database and run the script on the target database members first.

Moreover, if you change the schema of your member databases, these changes will not be picked up and synched by the service. Only columns explicitly selected as part of the Dataset in Sync Group will be synched. If you want to include or remove columns as result of a schema change, you will have to modify the sync group.

https://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/things-you-need-to-know-about-sql-data-sync-service/

Comment: The question was about offline sync in Azure Mobile Apps, not the data sync service.

Comment: Yes In azure mobile services the sync option is for the data between a local storage (sqlite) and SQL azure.